# Find the exponential value using NSExpression?

Tags: objective-c, ios, expression

I am trying to calculate exponential values using `NSExpression` like below:

```
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2];        
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];

NSArray *arrNum=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:number1,number2,nil];
NSExpression *arrayExpression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: arrNum];

NSArray *arrExp=[NSArray arrayWithObject:arrayExpression]; 

NSExpression* expression =[NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"raise:toPower:" arguments:arrExp];

NSLog(@"powerExp:%@",expression);

int  resultSum = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context: nil] intValue];

NSLog(@"resultnum:%f",resultSum);
```

I got the error:

> -[__NSArrayI doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7439e60
>   2012-10-22 16:04:04.034 operator[3958:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7439e60'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2];
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];

NSExpression *expr1 = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:number1];
NSExpression *expr2 = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:number2];

NSArray *exprArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:expr1, expr2, nil];

NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"raise:toPower:" arguments:exprArgs];
NSLog(@"powerExp:%@",expression);

int resultSum = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context: nil] intValue];
NSLog(@"resultnum:%d",resultSum);
```

Output:

```
powerExp:2 ** 4
resultnum:16
```

Comment: @sayalSnaking: Changing the question (in particular after you got an answer) is a bad idea. Nobody will understand the answers that were given to your first question. - If you have a new problem then post a new question! I will rollback your change.

Comment: I am not able to ask question because of my question closed,so only am edit this question.

Comment: NSString *strCal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"((%d%@)%@)%@",number,strMinus,strDivide,strMultiple];
    NSExpression *exp=[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:strCal];
    float result=[[exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"result:%f",result);                               Printing description of strCal:
((28-18)/87)*100                                                       expected output should be 11.49 but i am got result is 0.0000

Answer (score 0):

`expressionForConstantValue:` takes an `NSNumber`. You passed it an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`.

The `exp:` function takes a single number (n) and returns e^n. Is that what you're trying to do? Or did you mean to use `raise:toPower:`, which takes two values?

Comment: Am updated my question to raise:toPower: but same error came.

Comment: `expressionForConstantValue:` still takes a single `NSNumber`, not an `NSArray`.